# More than 3 sounds playing at once in flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, audio

I have noticed that while trying to play sounds in Flex 4 some weird things happen.  Playing 1 sound (say a button click) on top of another (say background music) seems fine but when I add a third sound everything just cuts out. Is there some sort of explanation as to why this would happen and if so how to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: do you assign every `Sound.play()` to a different `SoundChannel` [ http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html ]?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a matter of dividing your sounds into SoundChannel objects and managing them that way.